# The Algebraic dependence of two rational functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How to show that the two rational functions $a(t) , b(t) \in \Bbb K(t) $
when $\operatorname{Char}(\Bbb K) \not =2$ are algebraically dependent.

(there is polynomial $P(x,y) \in \Bbb K[x,y]$ such that $P(a(t),b(t))=0$)?

Comment: Should this not be obvious? $K(t)/K$ has transcendence degree 1. So $K(t)/K(a)$ has transcendence degree=0. Then you see $K(t)/K(a)$ is algebraic. In particular $b\in K(t)$ algebraic over $K(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user45765 already gave an answer.

Let us assume that $a$ is not a constant.
We may assume $a(t) = \frac{c(t)}{d(t)}$, where $c(t),d(t)\in K[t]$ and $d(t) \neq 0$. 
Now $f(x)=c(x) - d(x) a(t)\in K(a(t))[x]$ which is not zero (why?), and $f(t) =0$, this shows that $t$ is algebraic over $K(a)$. Therefore $K(t)$ is an algebraic extension of $K(a)$, in particular, $b$ is algebraic over $K(a)$.